# Submit form without redirect & display flash message

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I've got a single page website and I'm trying to submit the '*subscribe to newsletter*' form (which just has one input field, email) without refreshing the page but just sending feedback by using **connect-flash** flash messages.

Right now the page reloads and I get no flash message sadly.

Is there a way to achieve this without using **AJAX** and its **preventDefault** method?

**Form**

```
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <label class="sr-only" for="subscriber-email">Email address</label>
                      <input name="email" type="email" id="subscriber-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <input id="subscribe-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Join">
                          </span>
                  </div><!--/input-grpup-->

              </form>

              <!-- SUCCESS OR ERROR MESSAGES -->
              <div id="subscription-response">
                {{#if locals.messages.success}}
                  {{locals.messages.success}}
                  {{/if}}
              </div>
```

**Route**

```
 app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
  var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

  //send
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      req.flash('success', 'success message');
      res.locals.messages = req.flash();
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Not possible without `event.preventDefault()`.